# Construction following 'faire confidence...'

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, pronoms

This sentence is from a novel published in 1960:
'On fit confidence à Piet, avec insistance, de ce qu'il existait un antisémitisme local.'
How can that 'de ce que' be explained grammatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On fit confidence à Piet, avec insistance, de ce qu'il existait un antisémitisme local.

That sentence uses a couple of formal and literary constructions.

1. *Faire confidence*: The lack of article is very outdated. In contemporary French, that can be *faire **une** confidence*, *mettre dans la confidence* or one of the various verbs *confier*, *avouer*, *révéler*, *dévoiler*...

> Avec insistance, on révéla à Piet qu'il existait un antisémitisme local.

2. With *faire confidence*, the required preposition is *de* (that is: *faire confidence de quelque chose à quelqu'un*).

   What might have been possible is:

> *On fit confidence à Piet, avec insistance, de l'existence d'un antisémitisme local*.

but because the author wanted to use a conjugated verb, the choice was indeed ***de ce qu'il** existait*.

The very same ***de ce que*** can be found in more common contexts, like:

> *Ils profitent **de** la gratuité du vaccin*.

> *Ils profitent **de ce que** le vaccin est gratuit.*

Answer (score 1):

On trouve parfois cette construction.

- ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avis)) Recevoir, avoir avis de qqc., avoir avis de ce que
- ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aviser)) aviser qqn que, aviser qqn de ce que;
- ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mari%C3%A9))  Loc. fig. (Se plaindre de ce que) la mariée est trop belle.

"*Ce que*" can be replaced by "*du fait que*", which is in fact "*de **le** fait que*" (but not idiomatic); the determination and/or the referent comes in cataphorically in the text.